# VBScript: How to run an exe as administrator with password coded in it

Tags: vbscript, parameters, cmd, optional-parameters, windows-shell

I am using the following VBScript and was not able to install the exe.
Please help me.

```
Set objShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
objShell.Run "runas /user:D08DVS3\administrator ""C:\Temp\SQLSP3.exe"" /wait /qs /IAcceptSQLServerLicenseTerms /Action=Patch /AllInstances """, 1, True
WScript.Sleep 100

objShell.Sendkeys "Password#1~"
```

but all it does is paste my password into my Notepad.

Comment: Don't do this. ***EVER.***

Comment: Is there a way to make this script work ?

Comment: Try [`ShellExecute` method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/gg537745(v=vs.85).aspx) with `runas` verb.

Comment: ShellExecute method is showing error when i pass username and password. Please help me with Syntax.

Comment: Sorry, it does not accept  username and password. It just runs your app with elevated privileges (same as _Run as administrator_ from right click menu) and might invoke UAC dialog. See code example in link provided by my previous comment.